# Deserializing to different types at runtime in haskell

Tags: haskell, types, aeson

**Background**

I'm working with the Aeson library to store and retrieve values from a file. I am using `Typeable` (and `TypeRep`s) to tag the data so I have a pretty good idea that it will parse correctly.

I have a Class wherein each member of the class has a function that takes a time (`Integer`) and updates itself ie:

```
class Update a where
  update :: Integer -> a -> a
```

All the values stored in the file are Instances of the `Update` class.

**Question**
I would like to iterate through the file `update`ing each value and write a new file. I would like to have the program determine at runtime what the data type of the chunk of data is, use `fromJSON` to create value of that type, run `update` on it, and write it back.  The type checker thinks this is a terrible idea because it cannot statically type check the fromJSON call at compile time and therefore cannot get the right entry from the `Update` class dictionary.

Is there a way to use Typeable (or Data) to get the type checker to do the right thing? Is there a better alternative?

---

My only thought on working around this is to create a union data type of all updateable types, and then use a case statement to parse the tag and choose the correct constructor.  I'm not real happy with this solution because I cannot add new types to the update class without also touching this union type.

Comment: If I understand correctly, your goal is to have a runtime list of all available instances for `Update`. This can not be achieved, I think.

Comment: I'd say the core question is how do you want to determine the data type of each chunk?

Comment: Petr, The first field in the JSON object determines the data type.

Comment: @JohnF.Miller I meant how do you want to map such a  field into the corresponding data type? You need to have some kind of a dictionary, either implicit or explicit. Implicit ones are problematic that they can (1) overlap, (2) include something unexpected. (Please respond using the [@name](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/192930) syntax, it then lands in my inbox.)

Comment: @PetrPudlák Yes, that is the question I am trying to ask.  How do I either create a dictionary (which must be heterogeneous) or use one of haskell's libraries to introspect on an existing dictionary at run time? Data.Typeable says that the code clearly knows what the name of it's type is.  Is there a library that will reverse the process?  Given the name of a type produce a constructor for that type.

Answer (score 2):

*(This is more an extended comment than a full answer.)*

> I'm not real happy with this solution because I cannot add new types to the update class without also touching this union type.

I'd suggest to actually rethink this reasoning. Type classes in Haskell express that a certain type has a specific property. For example, that numbers can be added. This doesn't mean that a program should/wants to use such a property, the property is intrinsic to the data type. And they're open - different parts of a program can add new instances, and the program's behavior shouldn't depend on instances declared in independent modules.

Your suggestion, to automatically parse all instances of `Update`, goes against the above sense. It can make your program less readable, and more importantly, create more problems in the future. If someone wants to determine how exactly the parsing part works, (s)he would have to examine the complete source code of the program and look for all instances of `Update`. I'd rather advocate for *locality* - the meaning of a program should depend on its "local surroundings".

It also doesn't allow to have instances that you don't want to use (for example only for testing). It also doesn't allow you to have 2 or more parsing routines, each working with a different set of `Update` instances.

Using `Typeable` to tag your data can be also problematic, as it doesn't allow you to refactor your code easily. If you need to change your types, you won't be able to parse your data.

---

So my suggestion would be to have such an union data type, but to simplify the corresponding boilerplate code.

Aeson already gives you the ability to derive instances using `Generic`. So you don't need to worry about `FromJSON`/`ToJSON`. And you can write a generic `Upgrade` instance once for this union type using Template Haskell, or using Generic, such that it'll be automatically derived regardless on the number of constructors of the union type. This will allow you to have full, local control on the serialization/deserialization process, with very little of manual work when modifying the instances.

If you want, I can also give an example how to write such an instance.

Answer (score 0):

After much research, the answer appears to be that what I was attempting to do cannot be done.  There are three libraries (Data Typeable, Data.Data, and Data.Dynamic) that allow type level data to be promoted to values, but nothing that allows value level date to be converted to type level data.  This seems to be a consequence of the way the type system works.  Types simply do not exist at the end of the compile step. **There is not, and cannot be an equivalent to Ruby's `Object.const_get` in Haskell.**¹

[Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45692382/163177) ran with my suggestion of working around this limitation by constructing a type which is the union of all possible types.  Indeed if one looks at lexer and parser implementations this is what is typically done.  For my situation I found it easier -- knowing that my intent was always to store my results back to the file anyway -- to make `Update` a data type rather then a class and explicitly write the dictionary. Rather than concern myself with how to make it heterogeneous, I just included the write to disk in the functions that are the values of the map so they all have a resulting type of `IO()`

```
data Update = Update {
    clock :: IO (Int)
  , updaters :: Map String (Int -> Value -> IO())
  , source :: Int -> IO(Maybe (String, Value)) 
  }
```

A value of type `Update` can then be created at runtime and stored in a ReaderT Monad Transformer along with the rest of the program's runtime configuration data. With the messy details of command and control and error handling *left out* an update worker looks a bit like:

```
updateWorker :: Update -> IO()
updateWorker u = do
  time <- clock u
  (key,val) <- fromJust <$> source t
  let updateFunct =  fromJust  $  lookup k (updaters u)
  updateFunct time val
```

---

1: There are ways to do this using Template Haskell at compile time, and it may be possible to extend this to run time with the careful use of the GHC API, but that is beyond the scope of this answer.